# Hi, I am wondering if this sentence is grammatically correct: future tenses

Tags: future-constructions

I am wondering if this sentence is grammatically correct:

> In the year 2200 some people will live on the moon.

Can I also write this?

> In the year 2200 some people will be living on the moon

Comment: Can I also use modal verbs like might or may instead of will construction in this sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to add a comma like this:

> In the year 2200, some people will live on the moon.

for the second one, it's the same:

> In the year 2200, some people will be living on the moon.

Judging from what the context seems to be, if you're writing about what you think the future will be like or something along those lines I think you should use the second one.

Comment: Yes - they're both grammatically correct. Like victoria I prefer the second one, though I'm not sure it needs a comma: it's only a short sentence. "In the year 2020 there will be people living on the moon" might be more colloquial.

Comment: Thank you so much!